# R, gbm-package, How to get a predicted response in a factor type

Tags: r, gbm

Good day! 
I'm using gbm-package in R. I want to get the predicted values in the factor type (in my instance: setosa, versicolor, virginika), without additional reforms of results of "predict". And then use table(). But I see:

```
           setosa   versicolor    virginica
 [1,]  0.02670639 -0.008701904 -0.013467212
 [2,]  0.02670639 -0.006228872 -0.013467212
 [3,]  0.02670639 -0.008701904 -0.013467212
```

Here is my code:

```
    library(gbm)
    attach(iris)
    data(iris)
    set.seed(1)
    train <- sample(1:nrow(iris), nrow(iris)/2)
    fit <- gbm(Species~., data=iris[train,], distribution="multinomial",n.trees = 5000, verbose=FALSE)
    predictions <- predict(fit, iris[-train,], n.trees = 5000) 
    predictions
```

Thank you!

Comment: like this: `attributes(predictions)$dimnames[[2]][apply(predictions, 1, which.max)]`

Comment: I get an error in the `best.iter<-` line.

Comment: nicola, thank you! I corrected my code.